# Middle Mouse Button Doesn't work

Tags: mouse

After I upgraded to 12.04 LTS my middle mouse button stopped working... it worked fine before the upgrade. I can scroll with the wheel but when i push it down it refuses to work. Can someone tell me how to make my mouse work again?

Comment: the same problem persists with 13.04

Comment: For me (14.04) it worked initially, but since yesterday it just stopped working.

Answer (score 5):

The same issue persists with Ubuntu 17.10 and Xubuntu 17.

I found this helpful, too:

https://askubuntu.com/a/902976/354678

Answer (score 1):

These instructions guide you through customizing your mouse, including reconfiguring the middle mouse button: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations