# Ubuntu 14.04, how to set middle mouse emulation? (no taps, real buttons)

Tags: 14.04, xorg, mouse, touchpad, 16.04

I looked for the topic, but I only find information on how to have middle click emulation (wheel click) using taps with N fingers.
I want to have the emulation with the real buttons under the trackpads AND mice 
connected through USB.
For this topic, I saw adding the flag in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, but it does seem to not exist / have moved in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable Middle mouse button emulation in 12.04 LTS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/160164/how-do-i-enable-middle-mouse-button-emulation-in-12-04-lts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In previous versions of Ubuntu I used to enable middle mouse emulation with [gpointing-device-settings](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpointing-device-settings/). The package exists for 14.04 as well, so I guess it still works:

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
gpointing-device-settings
```

**Update 1:** gpointing-device-settings crashes on 14.04. But I found a workaround to manually enable middle mouse emulation in dconf:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

Navigate to */org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse* and activate *middle-button-enabled*.

**Update 2:** None of the methods above are still valid for 16.04 LTS. But the first step from [this official workaround](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Quirks#A2-button_Mice) helped. *Note that the remaining steps of the guide might not be applicable.*

Create the file */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/middle-mouse-button.conf* and insert

```
Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "middle button emulation class"
     MatchIsPointer "on"
     Option "Emulate3Buttons" "on"
EndSection
```

**Update 3:** This changed again after Ubuntu uses Gnome again. For 17.10, 18.04 and so forth the setting can be applied using the *Gnome Tweak Tool* as described in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974377/mouse-middle-click-copy-and-paste-in-ubuntu-17-10): *Keyboard & Mouse -> Middle Click Paste*

Comment: thank you. It didn't work for me (gnome+ xmonad, touchpad) though. I resorted to "synclient TapButton3=2" and use triple tap as copy

Answer (score 1):

Following up @jotrocken's answer, the configuration almost works. It should be:

```
Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "middle button emulation class"
     MatchIsPointer "on"
     Option "Emulate3Buttons" "True"
EndSection
```

Then restart lightdm or other DM running on your system currently.