# Mouse middle click copy-and-paste in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, mouse, clipboard

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 (and switching to the vanilla GNOME desktop, but I'm not sure if that's relevant), left-click select-to-copy and middle-click-to-paste no longer works.

I found [this documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-middleclick.html) which suggests the change is deliberate, but can't see instructions anywhere on how to change it back.

Is it possible to get it back?

Comment: On default  Ubuntu 17.10 desktop (so, no vanilla Gnome), middle click paste works as usual. Maybe it's a change in Gnome.

Comment: For anyone who comes along with the same problem:  Rebooting fixed this for me.  It seems to happen every so often (but is fixed in 18.04).

Answer (score 4):

You may use the indispensable *(GNOME) Tweaks* to achieve your goal.

First install it (if not installed already) by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then launch Tweaks and go to *Keyboard & Mouse* section and toggle on the "*Middle Click Paste*" option.

[image]

Comment: On plain Ubuntu 17.10 `gnome-tweak-tool` is preinstalled, since it's included in the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package.

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't work.  I have "Middle click paste" switch to on, and I've tried enabling it and disabling it, but it still doesn't work (I'm trying to copy & paste from one terminal to another).

Comment: @gerlos I don't have a fresh installation, but I tried a live USB session. Tweaks  was not there, nor `dconf-editor`.

Comment: @Tom Not sure if it's yet-another-thing-not-working-in-Wayland issue. Try to switch to an Xorg session and see if it works there.

Comment: @pomsky not sure where the problem may be. I just downloaded Ubuntu 17.10 ISO and tried to install it on a VM, and after first boot both middle click paste is working and `gnome-tweak-tool` is installed.

Comment: On my system (upgraded from a previous Ubuntu version), turning `Middle Click Paste` does **not** disable middle-click pasting. That’s very odd.

Comment: On 20.04, I tried to do this to *disable* the behavior, but Middle Click Paste is already switched off.

Answer (score 0):

### This particular problem

In Ubuntu 17.10 running Wayland as well as Xorg, left-click select-to-copy and middle-click-to-paste both work for me (like in previous versions). I have a fresh installation.

I would guess that some setting from the previous version is causing your problem. Many fundamental things have changed in 17.10, so I think it is better to make a fresh installation.

### Fresh installation often easiest and fastest

It is often easiest and fastest to make a fresh installation instead of upgrading from a previous version.

- Backup your personal files.
- Install a fresh system.
- Install the additional program packages that you remember (that you need).
- Copy back your personal files from the backup. It helps if you use a separate **`data`** partition for your personal data.
- Later on, when you need another program package, install it. This way you will get rid of old program packages, that you will not use.

Answer (score 0):

When I listen gnome-tweaks with `dconf watch /`, `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-enable-primary-paste` parameter is setting value but not working, I think gnome not listening for this value change.

So use this, it is working:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste true
```