# Is mouse middle click copy-and-paste a bug?

Tags: mouse, copy-and-paste

When you **select some text** (not copy) and then click the **middle button of the mouse** somewhere, **the text gets pasted there** without being copied on Ubuntu 20.04.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: It is a feature, not a bug! It is a feature known and utilized for decades of years.

Comment: A feature, of course. It's actually considered "the Linux way" by many.

Comment: See also this: https://askubuntu.com/a/974382/855322

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug.

Highlight-and-middle-click-paste has been a standard Linux feature for decades.