# XFCE - Emulate third button in laptop

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, touchpad, xfce

In KDE there is an option where the user can configure the double tap on the touchpad for emulating the third button. Then the user can open new tabs in Firefox or paste the content selected on the terminal just using a tapping with two fingers.

However, I did not find this option in XFCE (Xubuntu 14.04). I've seen the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/160175/171961) suggested for XFCE running on Ubuntu 12.04, but it does not work in my case.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Stick the following into a shell script and arrange for it to run at login:

```
#!/bin/sh
synclient TapButton1=1
synclient TapButton2=3
synclient TapButton3=2
```

That'll make a single-finger tap do a single-click, two-finger tap does a right-click, and three-finger tap does a middle-click.